# ADF managed identity for Key Vault Access

Tags: terraform, azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault

I am trying to create Azure data factory with Azure Key Vault with Terraform but when I try to provide the system assigned id of ADF for Key Vault access, I get the following error:

**Error: Invalid index**

```
  on Keyvault.tf line 46, in resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "adfaccess":
  46:   object_id    = azurerm_data_factory.datafactory.identity[0].principal_id
    |----------------
    | azurerm_data_factory.datafactory.identity is empty list of object
The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

Code snippet:

```
resource "azurerm_data_factory" "datafactory" {
  name                = "${local.prefix_kebab}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.RG.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.RG.name
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "adfaccess" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.appvault.id
  tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id    = azurerm_data_factory.datafactory.identity.0.principal_id
  key_permissions = [
    "get", "list", "update", "delete",
  ]
  secret_permissions = [
     "get", "list"
  ]
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy  = true
  }
}
```

**Expected Behaviour:**

It should create an adf identity entry in key vault access policy

Comment: Hello @el07, using you code only I am able to perform it successfully . I am using terraform version Terraform v1.0.5
on windows_amd64 and provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.77.0

Comment: May i please know what versions are you using?

Comment: It was my bad.. I didn't realize the keyvault was getting soft deleted when I removed the rg prior to this. It worked after I deleted the keyvault properly.